# Creating second Developer Account

Tags: apple-id, developer-program

Is it better to create new Apple ID for my developer account, or is it ok to use my existing one?

And what are the rules regarding names (like can I use nickname or I have to use my real one)?

I'm individual not a company, and will be creating an individual account.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it better to create new Apple ID for my developer account, or is it ok to use my existing one?

I would recommend creating a new one. Apple doesn't seem to care either way, but it's usually a good idea to separate the two accounts.

> And what are the rules regarding names (like can I use nickname or I have to use my real one)?

You have to use your real name. This is for identification and since the agreement is legally binding, I wouldn't risk it (plus, do you really want DenverCoder9 to show up on your banking records?).

Comment: Thank You. Guess i will create new Gmail then new Apple ID.